# jquery how to toggle on mouse enter or hover?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, mouseevent, toggle

I am trying to get a jQuery toggle to work on either hover or mouse enter but don't quite understand how to get it to work. At the moment I have set it up to toggle on click which works fine. Ideally i would like it on click for mobile devices but for desktop i prefer the hover effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/d8k3cn6a/

Here is my markup

```js
  $('#step1').click(function () {
      $('#step1 .design-steps, #step1 .hidden-steps').fadeToggle();
    });
    
     $('#step2').click(function () {
      $('#step2 .design-steps, #step2 .hidden-steps').fadeToggle();
    });
    
    $('.design-box').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.design-steps').hide;
    $('.hidden-steps').show;   
    
      $('.design-box').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.design-steps').show;
    $('.hidden-steps').hide;   

});
```

```css
.design-box {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.design-box:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.design-steps {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hidden-steps {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hidden-steps p {
  font-size: 80%;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.design-box h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.numbers {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="design-box" id="step1">
              <div class="design-steps">
                <span class="numbers">1</span>
                <h1>heading</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="hidden-steps">
                <p>Testing testing testing step 1</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="design-box" id="step2">
              <div class="design-steps">
                <span class="numbers">2</span>
                <h1>heading</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="hidden-steps">
                <p>Testing testing testing step 2</p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: It is working fine for hovering the mouse in chrome desktop version

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You must at least attempt to do that alone.

Comment: I'm just looking for advice not for anyone to do this for me, I have added to the original markup what i tried to do regarding mouse enter and leave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't see any reason to do this with jQuery, since you said you are looking for a `hover` solution (and not click).

Pure css is always better:

```css
.design-box {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.design-box:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.design-steps {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.hidden-steps {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.hidden-steps p {
  font-size: 80%;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.design-box h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.numbers {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.design-box:hover .design-steps {
  opacity: 0;
}
.design-box:hover .hidden-steps {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="design-box" id="step1">
  <div class="design-steps">
    <span class="numbers">1</span>
    <h1>heading</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-steps">
    <p>Testing testing testing step 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="design-box" id="step2">
  <div class="design-steps">
    <span class="numbers">2</span>
    <h1>heading</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-steps">
    <p>Testing testing testing step 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked great many thanks for that much appreciated, i always forget you can do so much more with css these days

Answer (score 1):

Maybe so?

```js
 $('#step1').click(function () {
      $('#step1 .design-steps, #step1 .hidden-steps').fadeToggle();
    });
    
     $('#step2').click(function () {
      $('#step2 .design-steps, #step2 .hidden-steps').fadeToggle();
    });
    
    

       
       
$('#step1').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.design-steps').fadeOut(500);
   $(this).find('.hidden-steps').fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.hidden-steps').fadeOut(500);
   $(this).find('.design-steps').fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
.design-box {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.design-box:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.design-steps {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hidden-steps {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hidden-steps p {
  font-size: 80%;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.design-box h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.numbers {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="design-box" id="step1">
              <div class="design-steps">
                <span class="numbers">1</span>
                <h1>heading</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="hidden-steps">
                <p>Testing testing testing step 1</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="design-box" id="step2">
              <div class="design-steps">
                <span class="numbers">2</span>
                <h1>heading</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="hidden-steps">
                <p>Testing testing testing step 2</p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly as well much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this. the action depends on the screen that it loads in. in mobile this happens on click while on devices bigger then `768px` this happens on hover.

you can change the screen limit in the script

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('#step1').click(function () {
      $('#step1 .design-steps, #step1 .hidden-steps').fadeToggle();
    });
    
    $('#step2').click(function () {
      $('#step2 .design-steps, #step2 .hidden-steps').fadeToggle();
    });
}
else {
    $('#step1').mouseenter(function () {
      $('#step1 .design-steps, #step1 .hidden-steps').fadeToggle();
    });
    $('#step1').mouseleave(function () {
      $('#step1 .design-steps, #step1 .hidden-steps').fadeToggle();
    });
    $('#step2').mouseenter(function () {
      $('#step2 .design-steps, #step2 .hidden-steps').fadeToggle();
    });
    $('#step2').mouseleave(function () {
      $('#step2 .design-steps, #step2 .hidden-steps').fadeToggle();
    });
 }
});
```

```css
.design-box {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.design-box:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.design-steps {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hidden-steps {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hidden-steps p {
  font-size: 80%;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.design-box h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.numbers {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="design-box" id="step1">
              <div class="design-steps">
                <span class="numbers">1</span>
                <h1>heading</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="hidden-steps">
                <p>Testing testing testing step 1</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="design-box" id="step2">
              <div class="design-steps">
                <span class="numbers">2</span>
                <h1>heading</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="hidden-steps">
                <p>Testing testing testing step 2</p>
              </div>
            </div>
```